# Python: Write Numpy array to a file with float precision

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, file-writing

I have a Numpy array of

```
a=[[ 9.9888e-01   7.6924e-04   3.5270e-04]
   [ 7.6924e-04   9.9888e-01   3.5270e-04]]
```

I would like to write it to file with six decimal point precision. I know that it is possible to print it to console using "%.6f", but how can I write it to file in below format:

```
[[  0.998878   0.000769   0.000353]
 [  0.000769   0.998878   0.000353]]
```

Could you tell me how to do this, please. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same format code as the `fmt` parameter of [`np.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy.savetxt)

```
np.savetxt('test.out', a, fmt = '%.6f')
```

Comment: Yes,exactly, why I did not consider np.savetext. Thank you @Daniel F